# MySQL - selecting the correct data within the correct week using week beginnings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select data, when inserting the data it has an auto insert of the date when submitting. So when data is inserted it inserts the current date. 
However, in my table I have week beginnings, so I am trying to select the data inside of that week:

```
mysql> select * from week;
+---------+------+------------+
| week_id | week | date       |
+---------+------+------------+
|       1 | 1    | 2014-12-29 |
|       2 | 2    | 2015-01-05 |
|       3 | 3    | 2015-01-12 |
|       4 | 4    | 2015-01-19 |
|       5 | 5    | 2015-01-26 |
|       6 | 6    | 2015-02-02 |
|       7 | 7    | 2015-02-09 |
|       8 | 8    | 2015-02-16 |
|       9 | 9    | 2015-02-23 |
|      10 | 10   | 2015-03-02 |
|      11 | 11   | 2015-03-09 |
|      12 | 12   | 2015-03-16 |
|      13 | 13   | 2015-03-23 |
|      14 | 14   | 2015-03-30 |
|      15 | 15   | 2015-04-06 |
|      16 | 16   | 2015-04-13 |
|      17 | 17   | 2015-04-20 |
```

e.g.

```
select * from table where date='2015-04-06';
```

However the data will not be selected and presented because the inserted date was 2015-04-10. The only way to retrieve that data is by doing this:

```
select * from table where date='2015-04-10'; < when the data was inserted
```

So my question is, is it possible to select that data from that week beginning? 
So if I select data from 2015-04-06 it should show data from the range of 2015-04-06 to 2015-04-12, is that possible? 
Hopefully I have explained correctly, been a bit tricky to explain let alone try to implement. I can add any more info if needed. 
NOTE: I am trying to use this inside of PHP so where the date is I would just use a variable, just thought I would say.

Comment: Look into "between" ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the week will always end 6 days from the beginning you can use the `between` operator and the `date_add` function like this:

(for your specific example):

```
select *
from table
where date between '2015-04-06' and date_add('2015-04-06', interval 6 day)
```

And using a php variable:

```
select *
from table
where date between '$name_of_dt_var' and date_add('$name_of_dt_var', interval 6 day)
```

Comment: I figured there was a way in SQL to do this; I was writing a way using `strtotime`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also compare the week of the date the data was entered with the weeks in the week table using WEEK() function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `week` is the same value as `week()`, the:

```
select t.*
from table t
where week = week('2015-04-10');
```

Even if the numbers do not match, then presumably you have some base date (such as 2015-01-01 and simple arithmetic would accomplish something very similar).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the most robust way to do this sort of week processing is to truncate each date in the table (in your example `2015-04-10`) to the preceding Monday at midnight. That way you can compute the week of each item by assigning it to the first day of that week.

This little formula returns the preceding Monday given any `DATE` or `DATETIME` value.

```
 FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -2, 7))
```

For example,

```
 set @datestamp := '2015-04-10'
 SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(@datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(@datestamp) -2, 7))
```

yields the value `2015-04-06`.

So, if you have a table called `sale` you can add up sales by week like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) weekly_amount,
        FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -2, 7)) week_beginning
   FROM sale
  GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -2, 7))
```

This is a very convenient way to handle things, because it's robust over end-of-year transitions. The `WEEK()` function doesn't work quite as well.

If your business rules say that your weeks begin on Sunday rather than Monday, use `-1` rather than `-2`, as follows.

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -1, 7))
```